# Lindelöf Property and Compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be  a compact space and $L$ is the smallest family of subspaces of$\,X\,$that contains all closed sets and is closed with respect to countable union and intersection.
The question is :-

Is all element of $L$ have [Lindelöf property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space)?

Remark:- Lindelöf property and Lindelöf space are same, since the definition of Lindelöf depend of regularity, I want to just add that every Regular space is Hausdorff.

Update:- We know that Lindelöf Property is hereditary with respect to [$F_\sigma{-set}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%CF%83_set). So I think this fact + the space been compact will be the key to the solution.

Comment: The question is whether every element of L has Lindelof property. What's a cover for an element of L. Is it a cover by open sets from the original topology or some other sets?

Comment: Member of $L$ is subspace of $X$, So, there should be relation with the original topology . ( I am not sure if this is the right answer to your question ).

Comment: Ok. That answers my question. I'll think about the problem.